# A SSIS Package from SQL Server 2008 to Azure - executes manually but fails when run as a SQL job

Tags: sql-server-2008, azure, azure-sql-database, data-migration

I have a Windows 64 bit server with SQL Server 2008 and a database.

I need to export data to an Azure database from this source and can run an SSIS package (connecting to Azure with the .Net Framework Data Provider for SQL Server) manually with no issues. However when I save the SSIS package and run it from a SQL Server Job I get the following error message:

> ADO NET Destination has failed to acquire the connection. The
>   connection may have been corrupted.

A bit of searching for similar issues suggested that I try running the package as a 32bit runtime but I still get the same error.

Any ideas on how I can get around this issue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try replacing the ADO.net connection manager with an OLEDB connection manager. The error should be gone.